# Regex. Spliting os blank spaces. Accounting for double quoted text

Tags: c#, regex, double-quotes

I am using regex to split a string. This is the input:
`Value1   Value2   "Val ue3"`

The output should be:

- Value1
- Value2
- Val ue3

What regex should be using for this?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: Typical SO is typical

Comment: Don't do serial downvotes on my posts. And I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
"\\w+|\"[\\w ]+\""
```

It'll match words and words with spaces in between quotes.  Since your output indicates you want the quotes removed then a `String.Replace()` can take care of that.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = "Value1   Value2   \"Val ue3\"";
        MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(data, "\\w+|\"[\\w ]+\"");
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value.Replace("\"", String.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Value1
Value2
Val ue3
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pT9aVh)